# работа с pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.int()
engine.say("Hello world")
engine.runAndWait()
```

> pywin32 и pypiwin32  установлены

**ВЫДАЁТ ТАКУЮ ОШИБКУ**

```
engine = pyttsx3.int()
AttributeError: module 'pyttsx3' has no attribute 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello world")
engine.runAndWait()
```